# Load SWF FILE in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, flash

I am stuck with loading swf on my aspx. I am supposed to retrieve swf from database and display on the page. My code manage to create the swf on the local folder after retrieving from db...but i can't seem to display it on the aspx automatically after downloading...and what should the code in the aspx be btw?...any ideas guys?...thx...

```
 public string swfFileName = "";


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string swfToDbConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
    try
    {

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(swfToDbConnStr))
        {
            // Assumes that connection is a valid SqlConnection object.
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
              "SELECT gameStorage FROM eGame", connection);

            // Writes the BLOB to a file (*.swf).
            FileStream stream;
            // Streams the BLOB to the FileStream object.
            BinaryWriter writer;

            // Size of the BLOB buffer.
            int bufferSize = 100;
            // The BLOB byte[] buffer to be filled by GetBytes.
            byte[] outByte = new byte[bufferSize];
            // The bytes returned from GetBytes.
            long retval;
            // The starting position in the BLOB output.
            long startIndex = 0;



            // Open the connection and read data into the DataReader.
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);

            while (reader.Read())
            {


                // Create a file to hold the output.
                stream = new FileStream(
                    //"logo" + pubID + ".swf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                "FBIS" + ".swf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
                writer = new BinaryWriter(stream);

                // Reset the starting byte for the new BLOB.
                startIndex = 0;

                // Read bytes into outByte[] and retain the number of bytes returned.
                retval = reader.GetBytes(0, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);




                // Continue while there are bytes beyond the size of the buffer.
                while (retval == bufferSize)
                {

                    writer.Write(outByte);
                    writer.Flush();

                    // Reposition start index to end of last buffer and fill buffer.
                    startIndex += bufferSize;
                    retval = reader.GetBytes(0, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                // Write the remaining buffer.
                writer.Write(outByte, 0, (int)retval - 1);
                writer.Flush();

                // Close the output file.
                writer.Close();
                stream.Close();

            }

            // Close the reader and the connection.
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
            swfFileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();







        }
    }
    catch (Exception exs) { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the content of a `FILESTREAM` with `SqlDataReader` is inefficient, even when using `CommandBevavior.SequentialAccess`. You are doing a buffered copy, but consider using [Stream.CopyTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx) instead. Declaring a Stream over a SqlDataReader is trivial, see [Download and Upload images from SQL Server via ASP.Net MVC](http://rusanu.com/2010/12/28/download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server-with-asp-net-mvc/) for a sample code of doing just that.

Overall though, with FILESTREAM blobs, is much better to just use [`SqlFileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream.aspx), specially for large content. See [FILESTREAM MVC: Download and Upload images from SQL Server](http://rusanu.com/2011/02/06/filestream-mvc-download-and-upload-images-from-sql-server/) for full sample, including both download and upload of large BLOBs via ASP.Net.

As a side note, reading into a file just to return this temp file may be quite expensive, depending on frequency of access.

Answer (score 0):

To display a `SWF` file in a page, you need a flash object to load it.  You should then point the flash object at an `ASHX` handler that will get the file from the database and return it.

Comment: yup...the ASHX method works and i modified the code using SqlFileStream as suggested by @Remus...thx guys for all the help....